# ¿Porque imagenes me aparece null,? ¿Como puedo guardar imagenes desde angular a laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, angular, api

He estado intentando guardar imagenes desde angular a laravel, siguiendo el siguiente video: [Subir imagen - laravel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yEuz8qjDk4g&t=498s), pero me aperece error de Field 'imagenes' doesn't have a default value.

el error es en el laravel pero no entiendo porque, cuando agrego el $posts->imagenes = $request->imagenes; si sirve sin ninguno problema pero cuando hago la validacion, de la imagen y demas request no sirve, estoy guardando las imagenes en public/posts/imagenes, si alguien me puede ayudar estaria agredecido, muchas gracias:

este es mi postController:

```
public function crearPost(Request $request)
{
    $posts = new Posts();

    if ($request->hasFile('imagenes')) {
        $file = $request->file('imagenes');
        $file->move(public_path() . '/posts/images/', $file->getClientOriginalName());
        $posts->imagenes = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    }

    $posts->user_id = $request->user_id;
    $posts->titulo = $request->titulo;
    $posts->contenido = $request->contenido;
    $posts->url = $request->url;
    // $posts->imagenes = $request->imagenes;
    $posts->etiquetas = $request->etiquetas;
    $posts->tipo_permisos_posts_id = $request->tipo_permisos_posts_id;
    $posts->save();

    //$tipos_permisos_posts = new TiposPermisosPosts();
    //$tipos_permisos_posts->nombre = $request->nombre;
    //$tipos_permisos_posts->user_id = $posts->user_id;
    //$tipos_permisos_posts->save();

    //return redirect()->back();

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Successfully created Post!'
    ], 201);
}
```

y este es mi angular:

```
  <div class="space-y-6 lg:col-start-1 lg:col-span-2">
        <section aria-labelledby="applicant-information-title">
            <div class="bg-white shadow sm:rounded-lg">
                <div class="px-4 py-5 sm:px-6">
                    <h2 id="applicant-information-title" class="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900">
                        Información del Aplicante</h2>
                    <p class="mt-1 max-w-2xl text-sm text-gray-500">Detalles Personales</p>
                </div>
                <div class="mt-10 sm:mt-0 w-full h-full">
                    <form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && submit()" #f="ngForm" novalidate
                        enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="md:grid md:gap-6">
                            <div class="px-5 mt-5 md:mt-0 md:col-span-2">
                                <div class="overflow-hidden sm:rounded-md">
                                    <div class="px-4 pb-5 bg-white sm:p-6">
                                        <div class="grid grid-cols-6 gap-6">

                                            <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-6">
                                                <div>
                                                    <!-- <label for="titulo"
                                                        class="block text-sm font-medium pb-3 text-gray-700"> USER_ID
                                                    </label> -->
                                                    <div class="mt-1">
                                                        <input
                                                            class="shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 mt-1 block w-full sm:text-sm border border-gray-300 rounded-md"
                                                            type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id"
                                                            placeholder="USER_ID" [(ngModel)]="form.user_id"
                                                            #user_id="ngModel">
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-6">
                                                <div>
                                                    <label for="titulo"
                                                        class="block text-sm font-medium pb-3 text-gray-700"> Titulo
                                                    </label>
                                                    <input
                                                        class="shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 mt-1 block w-full sm:text-sm border border-gray-300 rounded-md"
                                                        type="text" id="titulo" name="titulo" placeholder="Titulo"
                                                        [(ngModel)]="form.titulo" #titulo="ngModel">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-6">
                                                <label for="contenido"
                                                    class="block text-sm font-medium pb-3 text-gray-700"> Contenido
                                                </label>
                                                <div class="mt-1">
                                                    <textarea id="contenido" name="contenido" rows="3"
                                                        class="shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 mt-1 block w-full sm:text-sm border border-gray-300 rounded-md"
                                                        placeholder="Contenido" [(ngModel)]="form.contenido"
                                                        #contenido="ngModel"></textarea>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-6">
                                                <label class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"> Cargar Imagen
                                                </label>
                                                <div
                                                    class="mt-1 flex justify-center px-6 pt-5 pb-6 border-2 border-gray-300 border-dashed rounded-md">
                                                    <div class="space-y-1 text-center">
                                                        <svg class="mx-auto h-12 w-12 text-gray-400"
                                                            stroke="currentColor" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 48 48"
                                                            aria-hidden="true">
                                                            <path
                                                                d="M28 8H12a4 4 0 00-4 4v20m32-12v8m0 0v8a4 4 0 01-4 4H12a4 4 0 01-4-4v-4m32-4l-3.172-3.172a4 4 0 00-5.656 0L28 28M8 32l9.172-9.172a4 4 0 015.656 0L28 28m0 0l4 4m4-24h8m-4-4v8m-12 4h.02"
                                                                stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"
                                                                stroke-linejoin="round" />
                                                        </svg>
                                                        <div class="flex text-sm text-gray-600">
                                                            <label for="imagenes"
                                                                class="relative cursor-pointer bg-white rounded-md font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500 focus-within:outline-none focus-within:ring-2 focus-within:ring-offset-2 focus-within:ring-indigo-500">
                                                                <span>Cargar un archivo</span>
                                                                <input id="imagenes" name="imagenes" type="file"
                                                                    class="sr-only" (change)="onFileChange($event)"
                                                                    [(ngModel)]="form.imagenes" #imagenes="ngModel">
                                                            </label>
                                                            <p class="pl-1">o arrastrar y soltar</p>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <p class="text-xs text-gray-500">PNG, JPG, GIF Hasta 10MB</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <img [src]="imageSrc" *ngIf="imageSrc"
                                                    style="height: 200px; width:200px; object-fit: cover;">
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-6 lg:col-span-2">
                                                <label for="url" class="block text-sm font-medium pb-3 text-gray-700">
                                                    URl </label>
                                                <div class="mt-1">
                                                    <input
                                                        class="shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 mt-1 block w-full sm:text-sm border border-gray-300 rounded-md"
                                                        type="url" id="url" name="url" placeholder="URL"
                                                        [(ngModel)]="form.url" #url="ngModel">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3 lg:col-span-2">
                                                <label for="etiquetas"
                                                    class="block text-sm font-medium pb-3 text-gray-700"> Etiquetas
                                                </label>
                                                <div class="mt-1">
                                                    <input
                                                        class="shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 mt-1 block w-full sm:text-sm border border-gray-300 rounded-md"
                                                        type="text" id="etiquetas" name="etiquetas"
                                                        placeholder="Etiquetas" [(ngModel)]="form.etiquetas"
                                                        #etiquetas="ngModel">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-2">
                                                <label for="tipo_permisos_posts_id"
                                                    class="block text-sm font-medium pb-3 text-gray-700">Tipo
                                                    de Permiso</label>
                                                <select name="tipo_permisos_posts_id" id="tipo_permisos_posts_id"
                                                    autocomplete="tipo_permisos_posts_id"
                                                    [(ngModel)]="form.tipo_permisos_posts_id"
                                                    #tipo_permisos_posts_id="ngModel"
                                                    class="mt-1 block w-full py-2 px-3 border border-gray-300 bg-white rounded-md shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm">
                                                    <option value='1'>Publico</option>
                                                    <option value='2'>Privado</option>
                                                    <option value='3'>Empresarial</option>
                                                    <option value='4'>Amigos</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="px-4 py-3 bg-gray-50 text-right sm:px-6">
                                        <button type="submit"
                                            class="inline-flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent shadow-sm text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">Guardar
                                        </button>
                                        <div class="py-5 bg-gray-50 text-right sm:px-6 text-blue-700" *ngIf="mensaje">
                                            {{mensaje}}</div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que hice fue lo siguiente: en el metodo getB64Extension lo use para agregar la extension del archivo, luego en el metodo getB64Image obtiene la imagen en string 64image y la desencripta, y luego en crear post alli se setea el archivo

```
  public function getB64Extension($base64_image, $full = null)
    {
        // Obtener mediante una expresión regular la extensión imagen y guardarla
        // en la variable "img_extension"        
        preg_match("/^data:image\/(.*);base64/i", $base64_image, $img_extension);
        // Dependiendo si se pide la extensión completa o no retornar el arreglo con
        // los datos de la extensión en la posición 0 - 1
        return ($full) ?  $img_extension[0] : $img_extension[1];
    }

    public function getB64Image($base64_image)
    {
        // Obtener el String base-64 de los datos         
        $image_service_str = substr($base64_image, strpos($base64_image, ",") + 1);
        // Decodificar ese string y devolver los datos de la imagen        
        $image = base64_decode($image_service_str);
        // Retornamos el string decodificado
        return $image;
    }

    public function crearPost(Request $request)
    {
        $posts = new Posts();

        // if ($request->hasFile('imagenes')) {
        //     $file = $request->file('imagenes');
        //     $file->move(public_path() . '/posts/images/', $file->getClientOriginalName());
        //     $posts->imagenes = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        // }
        $file = $request['imagenes'];
        if ($file) {
            // Obtener los datos de la imagen
            $img = $this->getB64Image($file);
            // Obtener la extensión de la Imagen
            $img_extension = $this->getB64Extension($file);
            // Crear un nombre aleatorio para la imagen
            $img_name = 'post_' . time() . '.' . $img_extension;

            Storage::disk('posts')->put($img_name, $img);
            $posts->imagenes = "posts/images/" . $img_name;
        }
}
```